# How to declare a thread id in c?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I am trying to write two codes. One with `mutex` and another without `mutex`. In my program, I have two threads. While declaring the thread ID I have declared this with `pthread_t tid[2];` But I am really not getting why the value is 2 here? I have got it from a sample code. If I make the value as 1 it still works and gives me correct value. If I make it `pthread_t tid[0]`, then it does not work. But if I put the value as `10000`, then I am not getting the right answer from my program. So, my question is what the value inside the brace after `tid` means? I have provided my code below:

```
     #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

pthread_t tid[10000];
int counter;


void* doSomeThing(void *arg)
{


    unsigned i = 0;
    counter += 1;
    printf("\nJob %d started\n", counter);

    for(i=0; i<(0xFFFFFFFF);i++); //
    printf(" \nJob %d finished\n", counter);

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int err;
    while(i < 2)
    {
        err = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &doSomeThing, NULL);
        if (err != 0)
            printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
        i++;
    }
    //printf("value of pthread %d\n",err);

    pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[1], NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's just a standard C array declaration. I suggest declaring to have as many elements as you intend to use. Without having seen your code it's really hard to say anything about the behavior you describe.

Comment: @Michael then why I do not get correct value if I use the value as 10000?

Comment: Also, your return value (`121234`) is bizarre. Usually, something like `1` or `-1` is used, or, even better, the macro `EXIT_FAILURE` (defned in `<stdlib.h>`). Also, it's more idiomatic to use a `for` loop where you've used a `while` loop.

Comment: @ooga but I get the correct result, even if I put there 1. Why?

Comment: It's called "undefined behavior". Anything can happen, including the "correct" thing, but it cannot be relied upon. At any rate, you're using 2 positions -- 0 and 1 -- therefore you need to declare it with a size of 2.

Comment: @ooga anything other than zero will return an error function. So, I have used a random value. That was my logic behind using 121234.

Comment: @ooga agreed with you. My logic also is to use 2 but I was just confused about why I am correct value when I am using 1.

Comment: Your logic is flawed. On many systems, the return value is only a sigle byte. Return the value designed to indicate an error, the macro `EXIT_FAILURE`.

Comment: @ooga I was not aware of that. Thank you.

Comment: What output are you getting when you set the size to 10000?

Comment: Job 1 started Job 1 started Job 1 finished Job 1 finished

Comment: There's no reason why a size of `10000` should change anything. Try it again.

Comment: I just tried and my fresh answer is Job 1 started

Job 1 started
 
Job 1 finished
 
Job 1 finished

Comment: I feel that you did not copy and paste your current code, but instead simply changed that one line. That is not good enough. You are making a claim that seems impossible, so you need to compile and run your program, note what occurs, then *copy and paste that exact program*. Also copy and paste the exact output. BTW, one small error (which should not make a difference here) is that to print an unsigned you should use `%u` instead of `%d`.

Comment: @ooga you are right. I was trying with the code which is without mutex. That is why I was getting results like that. But still I am confused, if I use the value as 2 I get Job 1 started Job 2 started Job 2 finished Job 2 finished. But when I use 10000 then I get Job 1 started Job 1 started Job 1 finished Job 1 finished. Edited code.

Comment: Okay, I see. It's the code without the mutex. That behavior is to be expected in that case. Basically, the threads are trying to update the counter value indiscriminately and that's why it gets confused. That's essentially what the mutex is for, to avoid that situation.